# Get Collection of Unlocked Fields - In Microsoft Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro for Excel which spell checks unlocked fields in a protected spreadsheet by copying them, spell checking, and copying back.

I am trying to do the same for Word.

I have a protected Word document, which generally has tables with questions on the left which are protected/locked and empty boxes on the right for entering text. I would like to iterate through them and spell check the editable boxes.

Here is what I have for Word.

This said all fields where "unlocked" which doesn't seem correct:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim oApp                  As Object    'Word.Application
    Dim oDoc                  As Object    'Word.Document
    Dim oFormField            As Object    'FormField

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set oDoc = oApp.ActiveDocument
    Set theFields = ActiveDocument.Fields
    For Each theFields In ActiveDocument.Fields
        'Loop through each form field
        If theFields.Locked = wdUndefined Then
            MsgBox "Some fields are locked"
        ElseIf theFields.Locked = False Then
            MsgBox "No fields are locked"
        ElseIf theFields.Locked = True Then
            MsgBox "All fields are locked"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This printed a bunch of stuff that didn't make sense:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim oApp                  As Object    'Word.Application
    Dim oDoc                  As Object    'Word.Document
    Dim oFormField            As Object    'FormField

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set oDoc = oApp.ActiveDocument
    For Each oFormField In oDoc.FormFields 'Loop through each form field
        Debug.Print oFormField.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

E.g. this was part of my debug.print:

```
Text5
Text5
Text5
Check37
Check37
Check37
Check37
Check37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormField.Name` returns the name of that field, not the text that is displayed. Also, when you're looping through the fields, you're prompting the message box each time, which doesn't seem like what you want to do.

The loop:

```vb
Dim lockedFields as Long
Dim unlockedFields as New Collection
For Each theFields in ActiveDocument.Fields
    If theFields.Locked = True Then
        lockedFields = lockedFields + 1
    Else
        unlockedFields.Add theFields
    End If
Next theFields

If lockedFields = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count Then MsgBox "All fields locked"

Dim incorrectlySpelledFields As New Collection

For Each theFields In unlockedFields
    If CheckSpelling(theFields.Result.Text) = False Then
        incorrectlySpelledFields.Add theFields.Result.Text
    End If
Next theFields

Dim item
For Each item In incorrectlySpelledFields
    Debug.Print item
Next item
```

If this is all in Word VBA, you don't need the `oWrd` and `oDoc` stuff, just go right for it.

Comment: This seems very close to what I want, except I want it to actually open the "Spell Check" window vs `Debug.Print`. I tried a few variations but I'm struggling, can you edit to incorporate opening the spell check window?

Comment: I think I know the issue, I need to copy it to new workbook similar to how I did it with excel, this is a great place to start, thank you!

Comment: Can't think of a way to open the spell check dialog, being able to interact with, then going back to your loop short of a static variable.

Comment: I just posted a follow up question if your up to it! Thanks for helping me get the ball rolling! --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904167/copy-from-excel-workbook-to-document-from-word-without-adding-reference