# Copy from Excel Workbook to Document from Word without Adding Reference

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm looking to create a spell check macro for protected word documents. I'm more familiar with Excel VBA and I just created a similar project for protected spreadsheets so I attempted to follow the same logic. So far my code copies misspelled words from the office document, into a new excel workbook and then runs spellcheck, but I am having trouble pasting the new value back into the original word document. I can't have this require "adding a reference library" as this will need to be portable and run without end user intervention.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SpellCheckDoc()

Dim lockedFields As Long
Dim unlockedFields As New Collection
For Each theFields In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If theFields.Locked = True Then
        lockedFields = lockedFields + 1
    Else
        unlockedFields.Add theFields
    End If
Next theFields
If lockedFields = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count Then Exit Sub

'Word
Dim objWord As Object    'Word.Application
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

'Excel
Dim objExcel As Object, objWB As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Visible = True
Set wb = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each theFields In unlockedFields
    If CheckSpelling(theFields.Result.Text) = False Then
      theFields.Copy ' Select text from Word Doc

'Paste into new workbook and spellcheck
With ws
 .Range("A1").Select
 .Paste
 .Range("A1").CheckSpelling
 .Range("A1").Copy
End With

objWord.theFields.Paste ''' This line doesn't work

    End If
Next theFields
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `theFields.Result.Text`. So you can do `.CheckSpelling` in Excel, then make `theFields.Result.Text = .Range("A1").Text`

```vb
Dim correctSpelling as String

With ws
 .Range("A1").Select
 .Paste
 .Range("A1").CheckSpelling
 correctSpelling = .Range("A1").Text
End With

    theFields.Result.Text = correctSpelling

    End If
Next theFields
End Sub
```

Comment: So simple, thanks! This is my first time working with cross-product vba and I refuse to use "reference objects" so it makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: No problem. A huge part of Word VBA is understanding the `Word.Range` object, which is essentially a space of the document anchored at two points. `theFields` is a range object, so you can just edit its `.Text` property willy nilly, which is what we're doing here.

Comment: I'm begging to realize that, hence why I like Excel VBA, Range is pretty clear! I posted a question to try to optimize the macro as it is working, but doesn't seem it should be this complicated if I can run `CheckSpelling` boolean I should be able to run it on the field in question vs coping to excel, spell checking, and copying back. --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905099/checkspelling-on-field-range-word-vba