# Checkspelling on Field Range - Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a protected document which I am able to run the following line, but unable to actually run "spellcheck" on the text and think it's due to my range declaration, can somebody point out whats wrong?

Eg: This returns `TRUE/FALSE` correctly `If CheckSpelling(theFields.Result.Text) = False Then` but I can't then run `theFields.CheckSpelling`

What I have tried:

```
Sub SpellCheckDoc()

Dim lockedFields As Long
Dim unlockedFields As New Collection
For Each theFields In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If theFields.Locked = False Then
        unlockedFields.Add theFields
    End If
Next theFields

'Word
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

For Each theFields In unlockedFields
    If CheckSpelling(theFields.Result.Text) = False Then
      objWord.theFields.CheckSpelling
      ActiveDocument.Range(theFields).CheckSpelling
End If
Next theFields

End Sub
```

Comment: Why blame the range declarations? Why not blame the protection? Have you tried the code without protection? Can you temporarily lift it while the code runs? Or use `UserInterfaceOnly` to limit the scope of protection?

Comment: @Variatus I haven't tried on a doc without protection, good point. I am not the document author and cannot remove or alter the protection at least I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Perhaps you can create your own protection on a copy?

Comment: To what end/benefit? I'm not even sure I can copy the protected part of the document. @Variatus

Comment: Neither am I. But if you could create an unprotected copy you could run your spell checker on the form fields.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm more comfortable doing it this way, I may not be allowed or supposed to remove the protection by making unauthorized copies

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers were you able to implement the suggested answer?

Comment: Haven't tested, will have to tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the

```vb
Dim objWord as Object
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

since you're writing this in Word.

You want to set `Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections = True` and then hit each range with a `theFields.Result.CheckSpelling`.